# Parse json to custom model using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a complex json structure that is returned from the server. The issue here is that I need to parse this json and deserialize it and store it in a new mapping structure - not like the json file. Can someone tell me how can I do this using gson? Thanks

Here is a part of my json:

```
{
"direct_from_operator": 3,
            "yearly_id": {
                "$oid": "559f9934783a8731def494dc"
            },
            "calculation_amount": 121.2,
            "handset": {
                "monthly_price": 0,
                "name": "Sony Xperia Z3 Copper (4G)",
                "handset": 475,
                "retailer": 3,
                "model_img": "",
                "payment_level_id": 1,
                "plan": 488,
                "model": 152,
                "upfront_price": 149,
                "model_name": "Sony Xperia Z3"
            },
            "internals": [
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "meta_name": "national voice unlimited",
                    "main_category": 0,
                    "is_primary": true,
                    "data_format": "Unlimited",
                    "ui_display": 0,
                    "loc_types": [
                        0,
                        0
                    ],
                    "name": "Vodafone Unlimited Min Voice",
                    "id": 147,
                    "data_level_mb": null,
                    "is_external": false
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "meta_name": "national voice calls only trailer",
                    "main_category": null,
                    "is_primary": false,
                    "data_format": "",
                    "ui_display": 0,
                    "loc_types": [
                        0,
                        0
                    ],
                    "name": "Vodafone Special Numbers",
                    "id": 217,
                    "data_level_mb": null,
                    "is_external": false
                }
        ]
}
```

**Note:** I want to store all of this in one model class.

Answer (score 0):

If your model class has the same attributes than the Json that you want to deserialize, try:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
YourModelClass yourModelClass = gson.fromJson(yourJsonAttribute, YourModelClass.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

1- You can create GSON models online by using following link: 
    http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
2-After this use following tutorial:- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: I am already doing that, I want to do a custom mapping and create a different structure - not the same as the json response